# Apache commons httpclient or Resttemplate of spring?

Tags: spring, http, rest

I am trying to figure out between commons http client and resttemplate which one is a better choice, if I need to create an HttpClient which sends a request xml and gets back a response xml. The xml contains metadata information which the server side will store in the database.
Also, what about the plain old java class of java.net.HttpURLConnection ?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitly use the RestTemplate which can use java classes of java.net package, commons-httpclient or http-component via the interface ClientHttpRequestFactory.

ClientHttpRequestFactory has some implementations by default:

- SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory -> for the plain old java class of java.net.HttpURLConnection
- HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory -> for Apache HttpComponents HttpClient
- CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory (@Deprecated) -> for Jakarta Commons HttpClient